# List all Labels of an email to Spreadsheet

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail

My emails usually has more than one Labels assigned. I like to search emails with a specific label then list them into the spreadsheet and show all other labels also assigned to the email.

Here's what i have so far, can't figure out how to get the other labels...

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var threads = GmailApp.search("label:Test");

  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  { 
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
    {
      var sub = messages[j].getSubject();
      var from = messages[j].getFrom();
      var dat = messages[j].getDate();

      ss.appendRow([dat, sub, from])
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Apps Script is concerned, Gmail labels are applied to **threads** and not to individual messages. (There are other contexts where this isn't necessarily true, as a [Web Apps post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74238) details).

So, you should use the [`getLabels`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getLabels()) method of the Thread object. It then makes sense to structure the output so that each row corresponds to a thread, rather than a message. This is what I did below. The script takes subject/from/date from the first message in each thread. The 4th column is the comma-separated list of labels, except the one you search for.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var search_label = 'Test';
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:' + search_label);

  var output = [];
  for (var i=0; i < threads.length; i++) { 
    var firstMessage = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
    var sub = firstMessage.getSubject();
    var from = firstMessage.getFrom();
    var dat = firstMessage.getDate();
    var labels = threads[i].getLabels();
    var otherLabels = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < labels.length; j++) {
      var labelName = labels[j].getName();
      if (labelName != search_label) {
        otherLabels.push(labelName);
      }
    }
    output.push([dat, sub, from, otherLabels.join(', ')]);
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
}
```

I prefer not to add one row at a time, instead gathering the double array `output` and inserting it all at once. Of course you can use `appendRow` as in your script. Then you wouldn't necessarily need a comma-separated list,

```
sheet.appendRow([dat, sub, from].concat(otherLabels));
```

would work.